# breaking a list in to lists in python?

Tags: python, arrays, list

I have the following `list` of strings:

```
data = ["1","0","1","<>","0","1","0","<>","1","0","1"]
```

What I'd like as a result is:

```
[[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

E.g. a list of lists where each list is delimited by `<>` and the resultant strings converted to integers.

Comment: Can you share your effort to achieve the solution.

Comment: I don't see how this is a duplicate given that the chunks are not necessarily evenly-sized.

Comment: @AndrewMagee: indeed, my mistake, reopened. The terrible formatting threw me off.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can try using list comprehensions with a combination of joining and splitting:

```
your_list = [[int(j) for j in i.split()] for i in ' '.join(data).split('<>')]
```

Comment: That will fail the second the list has a number in it with more than one digit.

Comment: How will it differentiate `["1", "0", "<>", ...]` from `["10", "<>", ...]`?

Comment: I fixed it now, but the problem seemed to pertain only to ones and zeros.

Comment: This may work, but *boy* is it an ugly approach, and a fragile one at that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  How is it fragile? It works without any possibility of failure.

Comment: It only works for input data that itself doesn't contain your chosen delimiter. You already had a sequence, why join then split again? You'd have to keep adjusting this approach for different inputs based on what data is contained. The `groupby` solution is far more robust in that it doesn't have to first destroy the input sequence. Also, your approach is very inefficient for large inputs; building a huge string then splitting it up is just a waste of memory and cycles.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to effectively partition at each `<>`, then take the resulting groups where the key isn't `True` (eg: it's a `<>`) and convert to `int`s, eg:

```
from itertools import groupby

data = ["1","0","1","<>","0","1","0","<>","1","0","1"]
new_date = [[int(i) for i in g] for k, g in groupby(data, '<>'.__ne__) if k]
# [[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: I tested your code and being stopped by this error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '<'

Comment: @mahya.khazaee: you have fractions in your data?

Comment: @mahya.khazaee so you have a single `<` in your data - eg - the sample you posted isn't representative of your actual data? What would you *expect* to happen for that?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you more functional-style solution:

```
data = ["1","0","1","<>","0","1","0","<>","1","0","1"]
reduce(lambda a, b: a[:-1] + [a[-1] + [int(b)]] if b != '<>' else a + [[]], data, [[]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this also.

```
l = ["1","0","1","<>","0","1","0","<>","1","0","1"]
m = []
x = []
j = []
for i in l:
    if  i == '<>':
        m.append(x)
        x = []
        j = []
    else:
        x.append(int(i))
        j.append(int(i))
m.append(j)
print(m)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1]]
```